# Only fullscreen activities can request orientation

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

in my app,I changed the 'compileSdkVersion' from 25 to 27.and i found this question below in android 8.0:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1953)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1891)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation(IActivityManager.java:5683)
       at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:6121)
       at lka.b(SourceFile:140)
       at llx.a(SourceFile:211)
       at amqc.run(SourceFile:3)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

I found a solution to add the following method to the activity:

```
//android O fix bug orientation
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 26) {
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

But I could not find the corresponding activity in the above bug log. Have anyone encountered this problem? Please help me.

Comment: which google's API u are using?

Comment: @TornikeQurdadze Are you referring to this version? com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 'compileSdkVersion' from 25 to 26

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you are not founding the corresponding activity cause you have your app source code obfuscated.

```
   at lka.b(SourceFile:140)
   at llx.a(SourceFile:211)
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to your android manifest. And put  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in any activity tags that you want to make portrait.

Example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```